# 'SELECT AddGeometryColumn' in C++ crashed

Tags: spatialite

I am using MSVC 2018 developed a GIS program.  I use spatialite API to create a SQLite geometry database.  The program always crashed when executing "Select AddGeometryColumn'. I don't know if I need to include a preprocessor name or miss a library in my project file.  I included the following libraries,

```
spatialite_i.lib
sqlite3_i.lib
proj_5_2.lib
lwgeom_i.lib
freexl_i.lib
geos_c.lib
iconv.lib
```

My program as the following,

```
CString sSRID = sSRID.Format("%d", srid);
CString qrybuf = CString("") + "SELECT AddGeometryColumn('" + recs->code + "','geom', " + sSRID + ", 'POINT', 'XY');";
char *errmsg;               
int result = sqlite3_exec(sqliteDS->getHandle(), qrybuf.GetString(), NULL, NULL, &errmsg);
if (result != SQLITE_OK) {
    acad_printf("failed to add geometry column. error: %s\n", errmsg);
    sqlite3_free(errmsg);
    return;
}
```

Can you advise?